How to horizontally scale debezium by adding more nodes for same db source to improve performace
I am using debezium connector for mssql to push cdc events to kafka. There are millions of events to be pushed to kafka per minute but its lagging and is not able to keep it upto the speed of updations.
I am running connector in kafka's distributed mode. I assume since it is distributed, we can add more node to read binlog in parallel and increase performance but there is no such information on google how to do that.
I saw similar posts but everyone asked not to use multiple connectors for different set of tables for the same database as this doesn't improve the performance as both of them still will read the same serial binlog, specially when topic prefix is same.
If not, then whats the benefit of ditributed mode?

You can run multiple task threads before needing another whole server process. But you're saying there's no documentation on how to run connect-distributed or Debezium more than once? Distributed mode allows fault tolerance, not just scalability

Can you point me to the link how to add more tasks and how failover is handled


tasks.max property exists on most connectors. But it cannot be higher than 1 for mysql https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#_required_debezium_mysql_connector_configuration_properties 2) If a task fails, then Kafka Connect should start and assign a new one elsewhere. Since the number of tasks is limited to one, this doesn't really matter. But if your server where Debezium fails, then you'd want the tasks to rebalance to a different server. They just wouldn't be reading on parallel


So you mean we cann't have parallel processing in distributed mode to improve performance?

Only if you pass multiple database.names can you have multiple tasks for sql server. https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-required-connector-configuration-properties
